# Showing the set with a supremum has an increasing sequence converging to that supremum.

Tags: real-analysis

let $A$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb R$ that is bounded above and let $u=\sup A$. Show that there exists an increasing sequence $ (x_n) $ with $x_n \in A $ for  all  $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $u = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  x_n$.

If $u$ is in $A$ then the proof is trivial. If $u$ does not belong to $A$ then for any $ \epsilon > 0$  there exists an $ x_1$ in $A$ such that $ u-\epsilon < x_1<u$. By density theorem there exists an $r_1$ lies between  $x_1$ and $u$, since $r_1$ is not an upper bound we will find an $x_2$ in A such that  $ u-\epsilon < x_1 < r_1< x_2<u$. Continuing this way we will get a monotone increasing sequence and then applying monotone convergence theorem we will get desired result.

```
  I want to know whether I am right or I am wrong.
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Your proof is flawed, take a look at @MohammadRiazi-Kermani's answer below. Also, consider accepting an answer by clicking on the tick mark below the vote buttons if an answer helped resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not convinced that your sequence converges to $u$

You have picked an epsilon and formed a sequence between $u-\epsilon $ and $u$.

How do you know that the sequence converges to u.

We know the sequence will converge to a number $l$ such that $u-\epsilon <l\le u$,  but how do we know that $l=u$ ?

Why don't you pick the terms of your sequence between $u-1/n$ and $u$ ?

Comment: This is right, OP's proposed proof is not accurate.

Comment: @ Mohammad Riazi-Kermani  Sir, since  u is the supremum of the set A but not the sequence $x_n $ so that's why the limit will be some $ l\leq u$ not necessarily u. Is that you wanted to say Sir?

Comment: True, that is what I  was worried about.

Comment: thank you very much Sir for pointing that. out ..but if I find  a sequence such that u-1/$n_k $<$ x_k $ <u for all k in $\mathbb N $ such that $x_1 < x_2 <... $ and   $ n_1 < n_2 <... $ then using squeeze theorem I can conclude that  $(x_k) $ is the desired sequence with limit u.Am I right now sir ?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari Yes, you are right with your new approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the proof when $u \in A$ trivial? How can we find a strictly increasing sequence that converges to $\sup A$ or to prove that such a sequence exists?

Comment: I am not asked to find strictly increasing sequence only increasing sequence if u is in A then I will take $ x_n $=u for all n and  by the definition of increasing sequence  it's not wrong.